# Not Found Page in React is not working properly because of Sidebar and Navbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

Hi guys I have a question I'm implementing a landing Page, Login Page and a Dashboard which have a navbar at the top and a sidebar in the left side. so inside my App.js I imported my components but because that sidebar and navbar needs to be visible only on Dashboard I implemented this way.

```
  return (
    <>
        <div className="App">
          <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage}/>
              <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
              <Route exact path="/register/confirm/:id" component={ConfirmPassword}/>
              <Route exact path="/password/reset" component={ResetPassword}/>
              <Route>
                  <div className="dashBoard-container">
                      <NavBar isLogged={loggedIn}/>
                      <div className="main-container">
                          <Switch>
                              <PrivateRoute path="/admin" authed={loggedIn} component={Dashboard}/>
                              <PrivateRoute path="/departments" authed={loggedIn} component={Department}/>
                              <PrivateRoute exact path="/tickets/assigned" authed={loggedIn} component={Assigned}/>
                              <PrivateRoute exact path="/tickets/active" authed={loggedIn} component={Active}/>
                              <PrivateRoute exact path="/tickets/unassigned" authed={loggedIn} component={Unassigned}/>
                              <PrivateRoute exact path="/tickets/new" authed={loggedIn} component={New}/>
                              <PrivateRoute exact path="/tickets/pending" authed={loggedIn} component={Pending}/>
                              <PrivateRoute exact path="/tickets/open" authed={loggedIn} component={Open}/>
                              <PrivateRoute exact path="/tickets/closed" authed={loggedIn} component={Closed}/>
                              <PrivateRoute exact path="/tickets" authed={loggedIn} component={AllTickets}/>
                              <PrivateRoute path="/settings/general" authed={loggedIn} component={General}/>
                              <PrivateRoute path="/settings/type" authed={loggedIn} component={Types}/>
                              <PrivateRoute path="/settings/priority" authed={loggedIn} component={Priority}/>
                              <PrivateRoute path="/settings/tags" authed={loggedIn} component={Tags}/>
                              <PrivateRoute path="/settings/mailer" authed={loggedIn} component={Mailer}/>
                              <PrivateRoute path="/users" authed={loggedIn} component={User}/>
                              <PrivateRoute path="/profile" authed={loggedIn} component={Profile}/>
                              <PrivateRoute path="/tickets/unassigned/:id" authed={loggedIn} component={TicketDetail}/>
                              <PrivateRoute path="/tickets/assigned/:id" authed={loggedIn} component={TicketDetail}/>
                              <PrivateRoute path="/tickets/active/:id" authed={loggedIn} component={TicketDetail}/>
                              <PrivateRoute path="/tickets/new/:id" authed={loggedIn} component={TicketDetail}/>
                              <PrivateRoute path="/tickets/pending/:id"authed={loggedIn} component={TicketDetail}/>
                              <PrivateRoute path="/tickets/closed/:id" authed={loggedIn} component={TicketDetail}/>
                              <PrivateRoute path="/tickets/open/:id" authed={loggedIn} component={TicketDetail}/>
                              <PrivateRoute path="/tickets/:id(\d+)" authed={loggedIn} component={TicketDetail}/>
                              <Route component={NotFound}/>
                          </Switch>
                      </div>
                      <Sidebar isLogged={loggedIn}/>
                  </div>
              </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
    </>
);
```

So My "Not Found Page" is showing inside dashboard only, with navbar and Sidebar visible but i don't want my navbar and sidebar to be visible, adding Route outside in the main Switch, than is shown always even if route exist. I know that inside Switch is preferred to have only the Routes not other Components but do you have any suggestion how to solve this. Thank you

Comment: Please include your code as text rather than images (For search engines, people with screen readers, easy of reading for everyone, easy copy pasting, etc etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you already have the answer:

> I know that inside Switch is preferred to have only the Routes not other Components

The easiest solution you can apply:

1. Create `<DashboardPage />` component by extracting dashboard container, navbar, main container, and sidebar. Main container should render `{children}`
2. Inside every component's file from the second switch (Dashboard, Department, Assigned, Active, etc.), wrap its content with `<DashboardPage />`
3. Move all routes from the second switch to the first one
4. Remove the second switch
5. Add 404 component in the first switch